# Index private GitHub repos with Python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I would like to index my private GitHub repos and issues.

I am unsure how to authorize a Python script:

[image]

In the above form a URL is needed. I don't know what to enter here.

How to authenticate a Python script so that it can access the data of a private GitHub project?

Comment: Do you actually want an OAuth app? If you just want the Python script to be able to make API calls to get information about orgs and repos you have access to then that's **not** necessary, the OAuth flow is for people to be able to e.g. "Sign in with GitHub" to your app. Just use a personal access token, per e.g. https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the hint. Please write your comment as answer, then I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: If you don't want to start from scratch: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub